# Pandas concat in a loop vs list.append

Tags: python, pandas, memory, arraylist, concatenation

I used 2 methods to create a global df in pandas with each row resulting from the filtering of another df. I filtered by looking for the minimum value in a calculated column generated by a loop, but I read that it is better to avoid `pd.concat` in a loop for memory.
Comparing with another method, there doesn't seem to be a big difference in time.
Is there a better method?

```
import time
import pandas as pd

technologies = {
    'X' :[20000,25000,22000,30000,50000,10000,30000],
    'Y':[1000,2300,1200,2000,1000,3000,5000]
          }
df = pd.DataFrame(technologies)
start_time = time.time()
df1_result=pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    df1=df.copy()
    df1['i']=i
    df1['Y']=df1['Y'].shift(-i)
    df1['Dist']=df1['X']-df1['Y']
    idmin=df1['Dist'].idxmin()
    result=pd.DataFrame([df1.iloc[idmin,:]])
    df1_result=pd.concat(([df1_result, result]),  ignore_index=True)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
ListResult2=[]
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    df2=df.copy()
    df2['i']=i
    df2['Y']=df2['Y'].shift(-i)
    df2['Dist']=df2['X']-df2['Y']
    idmin=df2['Dist'].idxmin()
    ListResult2.append(df2.iloc[idmin,:].values.tolist())

df_result2 = pd.DataFrame (ListResult2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a refactored version of what you're doing:

```
rows = list()
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    s = df.X-df.Y.shift(-i)
    idx_min = s.idxmin()
    row = [df.X[idx_min], df.Y.shift(-i)[idx_min], i, s[idx_min]]
    rows.append(row)

result = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['X','Y','i','Dist'])
print(result)

       X       Y  i     Dist
0  10000  3000.0  0   7000.0
1  10000  5000.0  1   5000.0
2  20000  1200.0  2  18800.0
3  20000  2000.0  3  18000.0
4  22000  5000.0  4  17000.0
5  20000  3000.0  5  17000.0
6  20000  5000.0  6  15000.0
```

Your second method is certainly faster than the first. If I run a test on each method like this:

```
import timeit
    
a_dict = {}

mysetup = """import pandas as pd
technologies = {
    'X' :[20000,25000,22000,30000,50000,10000,30000],
    'Y':[1000,2300,1200,2000,1000,3000,5000]
          }
df = pd.DataFrame(technologies)
"""

mycode = '''
df1_result=pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    df1=df.copy()
    df1['i']=i
    df1['Y']=df1['Y'].shift(-i)
    df1['Dist']=df1['X']-df1['Y']
    idmin=df1['Dist'].idxmin()
    result=pd.DataFrame([df1.iloc[idmin,:]])
    df1_result=pd.concat(([df1_result, result]),  ignore_index=True)
'''

a_dict['method 1'] = timeit.timeit(setup = mysetup,stmt = mycode,number = 10000)

# and then for method 2, 3 in the same way...
```

the result is as followed:

```
timed = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a_dict, orient='index', columns=['time (seconds)'])
timed['perc'] = timed['time (seconds)']/timed['time (seconds)'].max()

print(timed)

          time (seconds)      perc
method 1      111.176106  1.000000
method 2       87.288192  0.785134
method 3       24.884230  0.223827
```

So, your second method reduces execution time by some 21%, while the refactored version reduces it by some 77%. I trust other users could find a way to make it go faster still.